# Find optimal parametr

Tags: optimization, regression

Let $y = X{\beta_{0}} + \varepsilon, $ where $X$ - nonsingular constant matrix and $\varepsilon$ - constant vector with $||\varepsilon||_{2}^{2} = \delta.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimization has nothing to do with $\epsilon$.

**Hint**: use the fact that for any vector $u$,
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{2}^{2}=u^{\intercal}u
$$
to write the minimization in terms of dot products.
This will give you an expression of the form
$$
\min_{\beta}f(\beta).
$$
Recall from calculus that extrema occur at critical points (points where the derivative is zero).
Therefore, next, find point(s) $\beta$ which satisfy the equation
$$
\nabla f(\beta)=0.
$$
You can use the [identities on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) to compute the gradient.

Comment: And I know that this problem has closed analytical solution.